# Is there a Pomodoro app available?

Tags: software-recommendation, applet

Is there a pomodoro app that's available for Ubuntu 12.04 that can be installed using sudo or from the package manager?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### [gnome-shell-pomodoro](http://gnomepomodoro.org/)

**For Gnome-shell**. You can use this extension in GNOME shell for pomodoro indicator. It works out of the box in many distros, like Ubuntu 17.10 (which doesn't come with Unity anymore).

Old versions were installed through:

- https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/53/pomodoro/

Current version that works on my Ubuntu 20 is install-able through `apt`:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-pomodoro
```

Homepage with instructions for installing on different OS distributions and versions: http://gnomepomodoro.org/

### [malev's pomodoro-indicator](https://launchpad.net/pomodoro-indicator)

**For Unity**. The [pomodoro-indicator](https://launchpad.net/pomodoro-indicator) as referenced by the other answerer doesn't work straight out of the box. We first have to [fix the icon](https://answers.launchpad.net/pomodoro-indicator/+question/198506) so it appears on the Unity panel.

Follow the commands and hopefully it works for you:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/pomodoro-indicator/trunk/0.0.2/+download/pomodoro-indicator-0.0.2.tar.gz
wget https://launchpad.net/pomodoro-indicator/trunk/0.0.1/+download/pomodoro-indicator-0.0.1.tar.gz
tar xvf pomodoro-indicator-0.0.2.tar.gz
tar xvf pomodoro-indicator-0.0.1.tar.gz
cp -R pomodoro-indicator-0.0.2/* pomodoro-indicator-0.0.1/
cd pomodoro-indicator-0.0.1; gedit setup.py
```

In line 112, remove # from the following line:

```
#package_data = {"pomodoro": ["images/*.png", ]}
```

Save the file.

```
sudo python setup.py install
pomodoro-indicator
```

Pomodoro indicator will now appear in the Unity panel.

### Reference

- https://answers.launchpad.net/pomodoro-indicator/+question/198506

Comment: What would be a good way to have pomodoro-indicator auto-start with unity?

Comment: See [How to start applications at startup automatically?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-to-start-applications-at-startup-automatically).

Comment: Thanks jokerdino. Do you think it's possible to run it in raring? If it's python it doesn't need to be compiled right? I tried apt-get but there doesn't seem to be a "raring" release.

Comment: @faB no you don't use apt-get but download the source and install it from there. I haven't tested the answer for raring. So, I can't guarantee you much.

Comment: This answer worked for me, but Atareao's pomodoro-indicator is much easier to install, nicer looking, and has more features: http://askubuntu.com/a/587843/21900

Comment: `pomodoro-indicator` as suggested by this answer works, but its extremely simple -- it has no way of setting up the length of breaks or work-periods, which is a pretty critical feature, in my opinion.

Answer (score 76):

### [Tomate](https://github.com/eliostvs/tomate-gtk)

> If you have installed the program using the old ppa repository uninstall the old version first. If you use an Ubuntu-based distro, such as Mint, manually set the RELEASE variable to the Ubuntu version number, such as 16.04, rather than running the sed script bellow.

```sh
RELEASE=`sed -n 's/VERSION_ID="\(.*\)"/\1/p' /etc/os-release`
sudo wget -O- http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/eliostvs:/tomate/xUbuntu_$RELEASE/Release.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo bash -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/eliostvs:/tomate/xUbuntu_$RELEASE/ ./' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tomate.list"
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install tomate-gtk
```

Comment: For Ubuntu + Unity this is currently the best choice that "just works".

Comment: If anyone is wondering, Tomate comes with an indicator. So you don't need to keep the full app open while using it.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on 14.10 because `libgranite0` was removed

Comment: This is what worked best for me (on 14.04).

Comment: for ubuntu 14.10+ see https://launchpad.net/tomate/+announcement/13290

Comment: tomate moved to [GitHub](https://github.com/eliostvs/tomate) and is now available from a different repository.

Comment: I suggest installing additional plugins as well.  
Oneliner: `sudo apt-get install tomate tomate-gtk tomate-alarm-plugin`

Comment: Works a treat in 16.04. To get the indicator, install tomate-gtk and tomate-indicator-plugin and then in the preferences of Tomate, enable the plugin.

Answer (score 30):

### [Atareao's pomodoro-indicator](https://github.com/atareao/pomodoro-indicator)

**Having tried others, I recommend Atareao's Pomodoro Indicator App.**

*Why?* It is simple, beautiful, configurable, has been tested in ubuntu 14.04, 14.10, 15.04, 16.04. It has a PPA and the developer is known for writing quality indicator apps such as my-weather-indicator.

My favourite thing is that the icon changes to reflect how much time is left. Here's a time-lapse screen capture I made:

[image: Time lapse of Pomodoro Indicator]

This is what the preferences look like ([polar night gtk theme](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/08/polar-night-dark-gtk-theme-for-ubuntu.html)):

[image: Preferences window]

**Installation:**
Copy and paste the following in the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pomodoro-indicator
```

Comment: Actually, the fact that you're able to see how much time left might be a big downside. Is there a way to disable that?

Comment: Your answer is actually incomplete, does not explain how to actually add it to the Unity bar (hint: open dash, start typing 'indicator', it should show up).  Also, IMO, it's not that great an app: you can't see how much time left even when hitting the icon or by any other means: that's useful info (for some of us - understand that @user89 has a different opinion: we should be able to choose).  `Tomighty` mentioned above looks way superior to me.

Comment: I tried Tomighty on my Lubuntu 15.04 Vivid Vervet, looked horrid. Atareao's is way better and simple, it's installed to Accessories as "Pomodoro-Indicator". I'd like to stay with LXDE and this is the best solution so far for pomodoro applications

Comment: +1 for instantly set up program with a persistent indicator and autorun set up on install. Just install and go. No exact numbers are an additional pro, because they can be distracting. One flaw is lack of sound on my setup (Ubuntu 15.04, upgraded before), but it's the same with Tomate.

Comment: @user390136 Pomodoro was invented with exactly that idea in mind. You should see the time easily. It's in the theory

Comment: it required additional 302 MB to install pomodoro-indicator. seems too bloated for such a miniature app

Comment: @NazarGargol only 32,8 MB for me in Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 18):

**[Tomighty](http://www.tomighty.org/)**

[image]

<strike>[Download link](http://www.tomighty.org/download)</strike> <-- Link does not work (404)

Tomighty can't be installed from package manager (it's java applet), but it's my favorite because it has an indicator with countdown timer right on taskbar. The downside is that indicator background looks ugly when idle because of white background.

So I edited default png and filled it with ambiance background color. Save the image as "tomato-24.png" and put it tomighty's .jar file. https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1a5Z.png

Comment: Its sound didn't work for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 11):

TeamViz Lite (or Pro) app (proprietary software). it's available for Ubuntu, for more information see this [downloads link](http://www.teamviz.com/downloads/).

Last update: Jul 13, 2013.

Comment: Please include info from the links. If they were to break, this answer would have little significance to other users.

Comment: PomodoroApp has been renamed to TeamViz for legal reasons.  http://www.teamviz.com/pomodoro-app/

Answer (score 10):

Someone has already mentioned Tomighty here but I've gone ahead and packaged it for Ubuntu [here](https://launchpad.net/~pwr22/+archive/ubuntu/tomighty)

To install

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pwr22/tomighty
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tomighty
```

Comment: the best one IMO. But unfortunately its very difficulty to find this installer for Ubuntu, so thank you.

Comment: Thanks!  Do you happen to know where the icon is stashed away? the white background looks horrible, I'd like to replace it entirely.

Comment: I believe it's inside the .jar

Comment: @PeterRoberts It doesn't work for Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: this is the most awesome pomodoro app I ever found. But it seems no longer available :(

Comment: `404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]`, `E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/pwr22/tomighty/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file` would be nice if people who knew this app file issues on the other alternatives, with its more beloved features

Answer (score 9):

It's not exactly an app, but [I've posted an answer to a similar question on Super User](https://superuser.com/a/669811/120246) That basically revolved around using the terminal to program your Pomodoros.

You'd be basically issuing the following terminal command to start a Pomodoro:

```
sleep 1500 && notify-send -u critical "break"
```

In order to introduce breaks, you'd be running the following:

```
sleep 300 && notify-send -u critical "back to work"  # a short, 5-minute break
sleep 900 && notify-send -u critical "back to work"  # a long, 15-minute break
```

That's the gist of it. You can find more details [here](https://superuser.com/a/669811/120246).

Comment: LOL, has no UI, but looks a great ideia

Comment: I have this alias on my `.bashrc`. It uses [`sox`package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=sox) for a nice guitar sound at the end: `alias pomodoro='sleep 25m && for NUM in $(seq 3); do notify-send -u critical "End of pomodoro"; play -q -n synth 2 pluck E4; done'`.

Answer (score 3):

The [PomoDoneApp](http://pomodoneapp.com) looks good. Worked fine in Ubuntu 16.04, don't know about Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

Another option: Google timer

Pros: no package required to install, no dependencies, no manually creating a Desktop icon (Zeegaree).

Cons: requires internet connection

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=google+timer

Comment: Requires constant looking at a page. However, it is a clever solution indeed. +1

Comment: It doesn't; there's an audible beep when the timer's done.

Comment: **[tomato.es](http://www.tomato.es/)** is also nice, open source and audible. Sit there on my bookmark toolbar. 

[DuckDuckGo also have a timer](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=timer)

Answer (score 0):

I just created a new minimalistic pomodoro counter. See https://bitbucket.org/dvtomas/osd-pomodoro

*A simple, ultra-lightweight, transparent, unobtrusive pomodoro countdown for Linux. Always on top, yet so small that it doesn't really bother you. And if it does for a moment, just send it a UNIX signal to toggle visibility.*

Answer (score 0):

**XFCE4**: [xfce4-timer-plugin](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/xfce4-timer-plugin/) (~500kB for XFCE users)

Add the plugin to panel. Add a timer for 25 minutes in preferences.

If you also want a sound, use any of these: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273098/sound-notification-in-ubuntu-terminal).

Answer (score 0):

### [pomelloapp.com](https://pomelloapp.com/)

If you are a Trello user, then you should definitely check [Pomello](https://pomelloapp.com/). I'm using it on CentOS.

Is proprietary software, electron-based. Is not affiliated, associated, authorized, endorsed by or in any way officially connected to Trello, Inc.

Comment: Don't use this app, very bad UX.