# Break Reminder for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, software-center

What is the best software for Ubuntu to remind us to take a break for our eyes (like EyeLeo in Windows).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

### [Safe Eyes](https://slgobinath.github.io/SafeEyes/)

Here is another tool for the same purpose:

```
sudo apt install safeeyes
```

Alternatively, you can install it from the PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:slgobinath/safeeyes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install safeeyes
```

[image: Safe Eyes Short Break Screen]

**Features:**

- Short breaks with eye exercises
- Long breaks to change physical position and to warm up
- Strict break for those who are addicted to computer
- Do not disturb when working with fullscreen applications( Eg: Watching movies)
- Disable the keyboard during break
- Notifications before every break
- Support multiple displays
- Pause automatically if the system is idle
- Optional audible alert at the end of breaks
- Multi-language support

For more details https://github.com/slgobinath/SafeEyes

Comment: pretty good,do what it says

Answer (score 14):

### Take A Break

Last update [2015-12-05](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Evlijm/takeabreak/trunk/files).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vlijm/takeabreak
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install takeabreak
```

- [Home site](https://launchpad.net/takeabreak)
- [Article on webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/12/take-break-helps-you-to-actually-take.html)

Comment: This is really useful and does what I wanted. Specially I like the effects which force me to stand up for a while. Thank you

Comment: I have used Take A Break and Workrave, and I prefer to Take A Break.

Comment: Just installed in my ubutu 18.04.4, I can see the app icon, but when try to open it failed.  Just flash quickly and goes away, won't let me configure it. Not sure where was wrong with my system. Could be some updated packages incompatible with takeabreak app.

Comment: it just shows notification,neither dim or lock  screen .not recommended

Comment: Is this the same as the package `budgie-takeabreak-applet`?

Answer (score 13):

### [Workrave](https://www.workrave.org)

Ubuntu comes with a Workrave package. You can install it from the command line with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install workrave
```

If you need a newer version than what is included in your distribution, use the official Workrave PPA.

The Workrave PPA can be enabled by entering these commands into a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --yes ppa:rob-caelers/workrave
sudo apt update
sudo apt install workrave
```

### Xwrits

A similar program, but thought for wrist care, is [Xwrits](http://www.lcdf.org/xwrits), also available from the Software Centre.

Last update: 2009-04-03

Comment: Unfortunately, Workrave resets the timers after a very short period of idleness.  The end result is that the breaks never get triggered. As far as I can tell there isn't any way to disable this or change the idle time before resetting.

Answer (score 9):

### [Stretchly](https://github.com/hovancik/stretchly/)

Stretchly is an open-source break-taking app that is pretty customizable.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

You have several [installation options](https://github.com/hovancik/stretchly/releases) like Flatpack, appimage or with snap

```
snap install stretchly
```

Comment: how to install via ppa or snap?

Comment: @ML_Pro precompiled debs are on the release page: https://github.com/hovancik/stretchly/releases/tag/v0.17.0

Comment: This want enable automatic updates right? Is there a ppa or snap?

Comment: I don't know. I'd open an issue on their Github.

Comment: @GeorgeOfTheRF `snap install stretchly`

Answer (score 4):

### [BreakTimer App](https://breaktimer.app/)

BreakTimer App is an alternative that I've recently made. It's pretty customizable and integrates well with most desktop environments. It's available on the Ubuntu software store as a snap as well as other formats [here](https://breaktimer.app/linux).

It's also free and open source, with all the source available [on GitHub](https://github.com/tom-james-watson/breaktimer-app).

Comment: I have been using BreakTimer snap for a long time, thank you for making it.

Answer (score 3):

### [GNOME Break Timer](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/BreakTimer)

> Break Timer keeps track of how much you are using the computer.
>
> Just switch it on, and it will remind you to take breaks.

> This application is intended as a replacement for drwright, which was included with GNOME 2. GNOME Break Timer is made for GNOME 3, with a status application that follows the new design patterns as well as tight integration with GNOME Shell. It is written in Vala and uses GTK.

---

Unfortunately I couldn't find any fine and smoothly working software like EyeLeo in Windows. And another built in solution from [this link from](http://www.maketecheasier.com/4-useful-applications-to-prevent-repetive-strain-injury-while-using-your-computer/) (2009).

Comment: Unfortunately that built-in solution doesn't work with modern Ubuntu, at least not with Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Iris](https://iristech.co/) (proprietary software), I use it for this purpose and it's quite cool

You can even have an excellent Web Demo here http://iristech.co/demo/

Comment: You probably could include some screen-shots and be more elaborate which made you think this is a perfect solution. I know the other answers arn't much more either, but this way you can make your answer stand out.