# A timer that automatically locks the screen to take a break away from the computer?

Tags: software-recommendation, lock-screen

I'm looking for a graphical or command line program that provides me with the following workflow:

1. Start a 25min session
2. After 25min screen is automatically locked for 5min (or maybe just turned black?)
3. Now I'm helped to take a break because I cannot do anything in front of the computer other than looking at a black or locked screen :)
4. After 5min, the screen automatically returns and I can continue work

Is there a program that does exactly this?

Comment: As a default feature you mean?

Comment: Hi orschiro, it' s done! See latest edit...

Comment: @JacobVlijm just installed the PPA version. What a beautiful application you created. Thanks again so much!

Comment: @orschiro Thank you for the nice question! It was really great fun to work on, and please if you find bugs or if you have suggestions, don't hesitate to mention it on launchpad (either the bug-link or the question-link).

Answer (score 89, accepted):

### TakeaBreak

TakeaBreak is now on **[launchpad](https://launchpad.net/takeabreak)**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vlijm/takeabreak
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install takeabreak
```

Recently (also) pushed for 18.04 / 18.10 / 19.04

---

Disclaimer: I am the author

Feel free to file bugs etc. [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/takeabreak/+filebug), or comment [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/takeabreak/+addquestion).
Thanks to orschiro for the nice question, and Rinzwind for the encouragement!

---

*remaining break- seconds (using countdown- option)*

[image]

*Settings*

[image]

[image]

---

### EDIT

An integrated & modernized version for Ubuntu Budgie is now available:

[image] [image]

[image]

This applet will most likely be available by default in Ubuntu Budgie 19.04, but can now be achieved [here](https://github.com/UbuntuBudgie/experimental/tree/master/unreleased_ready_to_use/budgie-takeabreak) as an experimental one.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87120/discussion-on-answer-by-jacob-vlijm-a-timer-that-automatically-locks-the-screen).

Comment: This link is broken can you please update it: https://github.com/UbuntuBudgie/experimental/tree/master/unreleased_ready_to_use/budgie-takeabreak

Comment: Working link: https://github.com/UbuntuBudgie/budgie-extras/tree/master/budgie-takeabreak

Comment: Is this the same as the package `budgie-takeabreak-applet`?

Comment: @Flimm it is! Modernized and integrated version of the original one.

Answer (score 25):

You may also want to consider [Workrave](http://www.workrave.org/). I found it easy to use and highly customizable. It also has some preatty nice stats about how you use the computer and how many breaks you take. Lastly, I believe it can also sync itself between many computers, which is useful if, for example, you work both on the laptop and on a school computer.

[image: workrave rest break prompt]

EDIT: It has many other features that I haven't mentioned, like suggesting some exercises for you to do while the screen is blocked. And it can take into account only the time you're using the computer, so it won't prompt you with a break when you come back from the toilet :)

EDIT 2:

#### Make sure you check out the "Reading" mode!

The above *feature* of only counting the time you've been actively using the computer can be seen as a bug if you're not doing much (no mouse, no keyboard events) because it will only prompt your break when you cumulate 1h of usage (or how much time you've set up). In these situations, enabling the "Reading" mode will make it prompt at the exact time, regardless of usage.

Comment: Thanks! Among the features, it can thus black or lock my screen during break time?

Comment: it can definitely block it. not sure about blacking it.

Comment: It's a nightmare to install.

Comment: @bartekbrak `sudo apt-get install workrave` ?

Answer (score 12):

Crude, minimalist, command-line way:

```
sleep 1500; gnome-screensaver-command -l; sleep 300; killall gnome-screensaver
```

That can also be turned into a desktop shortcut or turned into function in `.bashrc`

Why 1500 and 300? because that's seconds, 1500 seconds /60 seconds per minute = 25 minutes.

---

Below is a script for a timer that allows setting variable session and break time, as well as methods of signalling the break.

Remember that any script on linux must be saved as a file and have executable permissions set with `chmod +x /path/to/script.sh`. Once that is done, you can bind the script to a shortcut as show in [How do I bind .sh files to keyboard combination?](https://askubuntu.com/q/15050/295286) or create a desktop shortcut as shown in [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/q/64222/295286)

When you launch the script you should see a menu like this:

[image]

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Author: Serg Kolo
# Date : Nov 17th, 2015
# Purpose: pomodoro timer script,
# with bunch of options
# Written for: https://askubuntu.com/q/696620/295286

#####################################################
# screenSaver function
# this one uses gnome-screensaver-command for locking
# and killall for unlocking the screen;
# $1 is provided from chooseBreakMethod function
#####################################################

function screenSaver
{
  gnome-screensaver-command -l; sleep $1 ; killall gnome-screensaver 
}


##############################################
# dialogBreak function
# this serves as "screensaver". The screen is never 
# actually locked but rather we open terminal window 
# with a simple command line dialog
# in full sccrean mode
# $1 provided in chooseBreakMethod function
##################################################
function dialogBreak
{
 gnome-terminal --full-screen  -e  "bash -c 'sleep $1 | dialog --progressbox \"TAKE A BREAK\" 100 100 ' "
}

#################################################################
# dimScreen function 
# dims the screen using xrandr; the --brightness 
# can be configured
# for full or partial dimming using decimal values
# from 1 to 0
# $1 is provided from chooseBreakMethod function
################################################################

function dimScreen
{
  xrandr  | awk '$2 == "connected" {print $1}' | xargs -I % xrandr --output % --brightness 0.5
  notify-send 'Take a Break'
  sleep $1
  xrandr  | awk '$2 == "connected" {print $1}' | xargs -I % xrandr --output % --brightness 1
}

##############################
# getSettings function
# This is where the user enters 
# the settings they want
# All the values must be integers
#############################
function getSettings
{
  FORM=$(zenity --forms \ --title="Sergiy's Tomato Script" --text="Choose this session options" \
   --add-entry="Number of Sessions (how many loops)" \
   --add-entry="Session time (minutes)" \
   --add-entry="Break time (minutes)" \
   --add-entry="Dim,dialog,or screensaver? (1,2,3)" \
   --separator=" " )  

  [ $? -eq 0 ] || exit 1

   echo $FORM
}

################################
# chooseBreakMethod function
# A helper function that calls appropriate
# break method, based on the value we got
# from getSettings function
# Because dialogBreak calls gnome-terminal
# this function exits, so it doesn't wait
# Therefore we need to add additional sleep
# command
###############################

function chooseBreakMethod
{

 # $1 is method passed from  ${SETS[3]}
 # $2 is break time passed from ${SETS[2]}
  case $1 in
    1) dimScreen $2 ;;
        2) dialogBreak $2 ; sleep $2 ;;
    3) screenSaver $2 ;;
  esac

}


function minutesToSeconds
{
  echo $(($1*60))
}

#################
# MAIN
#################

# get user settings and store them into array
# Item 0 : num sessions
# Item 1 : session duration
# Item 2 : break duration
# Item 3 : break method - lockscreen, dialog, or just
# turn off the screen 
# SETS == settings
SETS=( $(getSettings) )

COUNTER=${SETS[0]}

#######################################
# This is where most of the job is done
# we loop according to number of session
# specified in the  getSettings function
#########################################

notify-send 'Session started'
while [ $COUNTER -ne 0  ]; do

  sleep $( minutesToSeconds ${SETS[1]} ) # session timer
  chooseBreakMethod ${SETS[3]} $( minutesToSeconds ${SETS[2]} )
  COUNTER=$(($COUNTER-1))
done

notify-send "tomatoScript is done"
####### END OF SCRIT ###########
```

Comment: I enjoy seeing the different ways that people go about these things. The adage about there being more than one way to skin a cat seems appropriate. Maybe fluff out how to bind it or how to make a desktop shortcut perhaps? (Assuming that completeness is your goal.)

Answer (score 12):

Here is another tool called **Safe Eyes** for the same purpose.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:slgobinath/safeeyes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install safeeyes
```

[image: Safe Eyes Short Break Screen]

**Features:**

- Short breaks with eye exercises
- Long breaks to change physical position and to warm up
- Strict break for those who are addicted to computer
- Do not disturb when working with fullscreen applications( Eg: Watching movies)
- Disable the keyboard during break
- Notifications before every break
- Support multiple displays
- Pause automatically if the system is idle
- Optional audible alert at the end of breaks
- Multi-language support

For more details: https://github.com/slgobinath/SafeEyes

Comment: Love it so much!

Answer (score 8):

I have used [xwrits](https://www.lcdf.org/xwrits/) for many years for this purpose.

```
sudo apt-get install xwrits
```

It defaults to a 5 minute break every 55 minutes, but according to the [man page](https://www.lcdf.org/xwrits/man.html) these times are customizable via the `breaktime` and `typetime` commandline options, respectively.  You can also control whether it locks the screen using the `+lock` option.  So to set it for a 5 minute break every 25 minutes locking you out, you should run it like this

```
xwrits typetime=25 breaktime=5 +lock &
```

Answer (score 0):

drwright was the typing break component that used to be part of gnome:
http://zeroset.mnim.org/2012/05/11/drwright-a-typing-break-application-for-gnome-and-unity-on-ubuntu-12-04/

and there is a ppa available (although i have not personally used post-12.04): https://launchpad.net/~drwright/+archive/ubuntu/stable