# lock screen periodically for some time

Tags: screen, monitor

For the sake of caring about eyes I would like my screen to be blocked e.g. every  hour for  5 minutes (or another intervals).  
Once I used one programme for doing it, but  now I can't recall its name.

Does someone know programmes that can help to get such functionality?

Comment: What do you mean by 'lock'? Do you mean the display goes black and then you have to type your password? Or does it mean just to dim your screen brightness?

Comment: both would be good.

Comment: check out "Is there a Pomodoro app available?" http://askubuntu.com/questions/158261/is-there-a-pomodoro-app-available

Answer (score 1):

To lock the screen, you can follow the answer to this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7776/how-do-i-lock-the-desktop-screen-via-command-line).

So you would write a script (in GEdit) containing:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
#: filename: lock-script

export DISPLAY=:0.0
gnome-screensaver-command -l
```

and save it in your home folder (or you could create a new directory for it).
If you only one to black out your display (without locking) change the `-l` switch for `-a`.

Make your script executable running `chmod 744 /home/your-username/lock-script`.

Then execute the following

```sh
echo '15 * * * * /home/your-username/lock-script' | crontab
```

Now `lock-script` will be executed 15 minutes after the start of every hour on every day. (At `01:15 pm`, then at `02:15 pm`, and so on.)

If you want more information about how to specify the period of time, you should check [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto).

BTW, for creating the `crontab` line you could install `gnome-schedule` which is a GUI frontend for this.

Hope it helps you!