# Timer/stopwatch in Ubuntu 14.04 Unity?

Tags: 14.04, unity

[Easy Stopwatch](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/easy-stopwatch/) and [Zeegaree Lite](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2013/06/zeegaree-lite-stopwatch-timer-ubuntu-13-04-12-10/) don't seem to be available in Ubuntu.

What timer/stopwatch can I install in [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr)?

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/538359/162573, http://askubuntu.com/q/158261/47206

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Have you tried "stopwatch"?

Terminal install command if you dislike the GUI:

```
sudo apt-get install stopwatch
```

It is also easily installable from your Ubuntu software center.  You find it by typing stopwatch in the search window.  Or if you prefer, you can also find it in the synaptic package manager.

The following link tells you more about it, although it is entirely the same information you'd see if you opened the Ubuntu Software Manager.

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/stopwatch/

Comment: If you don't need high precision, beware of stopwatch's CPU usage - around 25% on my machine, compared to 0.3% for gtimer.

Answer (score 38):

**Gnome Clocks** is good and installs easily through the Ubuntu software manager, at least on 18.04, or from the command line through `sudo apt install gnome-clocks`. It has fairly few dependencies (at least no Gnome Shell required).

It has a stopwatch and a timer, plus world clocks and alarms:

[image: screenshot]

https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-clocks/stable/

The [online stopwatch and timer](https://www.online-stopwatch.com/) is good and easy but seems to take significant cpu in chrome. Gnome Clocks is very low on cpu overhead.

Comment: One problem I noticed is that it's window is very large, and can't resize it to smaller.

Comment: good one, was just about to propose the same, I found after a quick research here and on google and then back to the market thing on ubuntu

Comment: OK, I think I spoke too early about whether or not this one is a good option. It does not seem to ask for much RAM or CPU but then it would turn my fan really loud for no reason, something like playing a very demanding game or similar.. just my 2 cents :)

Answer (score 9):

A quick search in Synaptic shows a few timers here, `gtimer` (appears standalone, looks to have several options & timers), `stopwatch` looks good, `gnome-shell-timer` (for gnome-shell, probably won't work in Unity), `ktimer` (has lots of KDE dependencies), `xfce4-timer-plugin`.

Do any of those look good enough?

In case they're not showing up for you, even after an `apt-get update` maybe you don't have all the repository components selected (main universe restricted multiverse). See this link for info on Repositories https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: on gnome-shell-timer - it does not seem to work in Unity http://superuser.com/q/538359/162573, as I am in Unity I will not install KDE or Xfce apps, stopwatch does it I guess, in the absence of a better looking alternativve

Answer (score 5):

I used

```
$ sudo apt install alarm-clock-applet
```

as a timer for my daughter. Works fine. I tried stopwatch and didn't like it.

Looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Both **Zeegaree Lite** and **Zeegaree** are now available at github. The reason why they are no longer in USC is explained here: https://web.archive.org/web/20190406121732/http://zeegaree.com/2014/10/zeegaree-and-zeegaree-lite-no-longer-available-in-ubuntu-software-center/

[Zeegaree Lite at github](https://github.com/mivoligo/Zeegaree-Lite)
[Zeegaree at github](https://github.com/mivoligo/Zeegaree)

Comment: I'm sorry but I've finally decided to stop paying for zeegaree domain and hosting.

Answer (score 3):

Having looked at a bunch of available tea timer packages I settled on the simplest homebaked bash script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

SND=/usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts/drip.ogg
mplayer "$SND" && notify-send "TEA: $(date +'%A, %d-%B-%y: %Hh %Mm %Ss')"
sleep 50 && mplayer "$SND" && notify-send "Tea: ETA: 50 sec"
sleep 20 && mplayer "$SND" && notify-send "Tea: ETA: 1 min 10 sec"
sleep 20 && mplayer "$SND" && notify-send "Tea: ETA: 1 min 30 sec"
sleep 30 && mplayer "$SND" && notify-send "Tea: ETA: 2 min"
sleep 180 && mplayer "$SND" && notify-send "Tea: ETA: 5 min"
```

> > <sup>Keep in mind that Ubuntu might suppress the notifications for example when a video is playing or the flash player is active. For cases like this append `--urgency=critical` at the end of the `notify-send` command.</sup>

It shows a notification at specified intervals and emits a sound via mplayer. Adjust to meet your needs.

---

<sub>On older desktop versions it was possible to use [zenity](https://gist.github.com/elFua/9f3cb814573e9fa316e71471ffd7f91f) to show an icon in the notification area with hoverable elapsed time, but under Gnome3 and current versions of Unity zenity notification icons don't work anymore.</sub>

Comment: Nice, I'm using this with the `play` command from the `sox` package instead of `mplayer`. You should exchange the order of the `notify-send`/`mplayer` commands so that the sound and notification both appear at the same time, specially if the sound file is not really short.

Comment: The answer is from a while back, and I stopped using `mplayer` (in favor of `mpv`). In fact you can as well use `aplay` (comes with **alsa**) or `paplay` (comes with **pulseaudio**) — both will have much less overhead than mplayer/mpv.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find anything I liked, but a web app seems to be a good contender.

http://www.timer-tab.com/ and also in the Chrome Store.

Answer (score 2):

If you need something super quick and simple, try

```
time read
```

which gives you the wall clock time from when you run the command to when you press the ENTER key again. (The `read` command reads a line of input from STDIN.)

Answer (score 1):

Try [gnome-shell-timer](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/gnome-shell-timer)

You can install it in the terminal with the following line:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-timer
```

Includes preconfiguration options, alerts, and an icon in the top gnome shell panel.

If you are are currently in Unity shell, log out, then click the icon next to your username. From the dropdown, select Gnome shell. Log in and follow the directions above.

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/538359/162573

Comment: @cipricus If you are using Unity, log out to switch to Gnome.

Comment: Thank you, but I will not install a desktop environment just to get a small stopwatch app anyway. (I should install the gnome desktop first. I do not have other session available except Unity and I do not want one.) I have edited the question to make it Unity only.